# WorkGroupSize = 0

Tags: c#, opengl, glsl, opentk

I want to use compute shaders in my program. I use C# and OpenTK for using shaders.
My problem: all my computers have 0 workGroupCount and 0 workGroupSize. I get these values with this OpenTK code:

```
int workGroupCount = GL.GetInteger((GetPName)All.MaxComputeWorkGroupCount);
int workGroupSize = GL.GetInteger((GetPName)All.MaxComputeWorkGroupSize);
int workGroupInvocations = GL.GetInteger((GetPName)All.MaxComputeWorkGroupInvocations);
```

Vertex, Fragment, and Tesselation shaders work well on my computers.
OpenGL version 4.3 and above. Why Have I 0 workGroupCount?

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation for `glGet`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glGet.xml), `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT` and `GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` are supposed to be retrieved via the indexed version of `glGetIntegerv`, `glGetIntegeri_v`.

> GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_COUNT
>
> Accepted by the indexed versions of glGet. data the maximum number of work groups that may be dispatched to a compute shader. Indices 0, 1, and 2 correspond to the X, Y and Z dimensions, respectively.
>
> GL_MAX_COMPUTE_WORK_GROUP_SIZE
>
> Accepted by the indexed versions of glGet. data the maximum size of a work groups that may be used during compilation of a compute shader. Indices 0, 1, and 2 correspond to the X, Y and Z dimensions, respectively.

In OpenTK, this is exposed as an overload to `GL.GetInteger` with an index parameter in the middle, so your calls should be:

```
int workGroupCount = GL.GetInteger((GetPName)All.MaxComputeWorkGroupCount, 0);
int workGroupSize = GL.GetInteger((GetPName)All.MaxComputeWorkGroupSize, 0);
int workGroupInvocations = GL.GetInteger((GetPName)All.MaxComputeWorkGroupInvocations);
```

If you were to check `GL.GetError` after each call to `GL.GetInteger`, the first two would probably return `GL_INVALID_ENUM`